# Databound WPF TabControl with ListView is causing scrolling issues

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a WPF application using a TabControl bound to a collection of the MyTab class. Each TabItem has a ListView bound to the Items property of the MyTab class.

My problem is that scrolling up or down in any ListView is affecting the position of all the others.

**XAML:**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeaderTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="col1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col1}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="col2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col2}" />
          </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabHeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code:**

```
public class MyTab
{
  public string Header { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
  public MyTab(int count)
  {
    Header = count.ToString();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
      Items.Add(new MyItem {col1 = i.ToString(), col2 = i.ToString()});
  }
}

public class MyItem
{
  public string col1 { get; set; }
  public string col2 { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<MyTab> Tabs { get; set; }
  public MainViewModel() { Tabs = new ObservableCollection<MyTab> {new MyTab(10), new MyTab(50)}; }
}
```

**Step 1:** Run app and select the first tab
[image]

**Step 2:** Select second tab and scroll all the way down
[image]

**Step 3:** Select the first tab and watch that the ListView has scrolled down
[image]

**Step 4:** Select the second tab again and watch that the ListView has scrolled up
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread pertaining to something similar which has a demo file (not sure if it works).
Hope this helps you in the right direction.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/14/10043253/scrolling-in-a-listview.aspx

Object myItem = myList.Items[20];
myList.ScrollIntoView(myItem);

http://www.mvps.org/vbvision/_samples/Virtual_ListView_Demo.zip

Comment: That thread talks about scrolling to a specific item. I don't want to scroll, I want to prevent ListViews from automatically scrolling in the first place.
I guess this is related to all TabItems using the same DataTemplate, which probably shares the status of the ScrollViewer. I don't know how to fix this though :/

Comment: What about wrapping each listview in a content presenter.Instead of setting the content and the datatemplate on the tabItem, you just do it on the nested ContentControl or ContentPresenter. Is this more like your issue? http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/wpf-databound-tabcontrol-form-state-problem-31647.shtml

Comment: I see that you copypasted the last reply there, and I read what it says. I just can't figure out how to translate his small example into coherent XAML in my case